# Python process synchronization

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization

I am trying to set up a number of 'worker' threads/processes, prime them with a list of 'commands' to work through and then get them to step through the commands one-by-one in step with each other.

**Update** I have had a few questions about why I taking this approach, so here's a bit of context: I'm using this approach for an automated testing script. I am simulating a multi-user environment, where different users are running an application that points to a shared resource. I want to carry out a sequence of operations simultaneously on an API from multiple clients.  I want to be able to control what each worker does to produce a repeatable set of tests. Without the synchronisation I will have no guarantee that the operations are carried out in the order I expect. Another requirement (I possibly haven't mentioned) is that I want to have the commands executed simultaneously. E.g. All writing a large amount of data to the DB.

I am using the `multiprocessing` module in Python 2.7.5b3 on Windows 7. So far, I have the following example working, which is illustrative of what I am trying to do.

This example gets the workers to write results back into a shared queue, so I can see the order in which commands are executed.

The worker (worker.py):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event, Lock

class Worker(Process):

    def __init__(self, execute, q_out):
        Process.__init__(self)
        print self.name, 'init'
        self.daemon = True
        self.q_in = Queue()
        self.q_out = q_out
        self.execute = execute

    def run(self):
        print self.name, 'running'
        self.execute.wait()
        while not self.q_in.empty():
            cmd = self.q_in.get()
            self.q_out.put((self.name, cmd))
```

The manager:

```
from multiprocessing import Event, Queue
from worker import Worker

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    workers = []
    syncEvent = Event()
    shared_q = Queue()
    for i in range(0,2):
        worker = Worker(syncEvent, shared_q)
        map(worker.q_in.put, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()

    syncEvent.set()

    for w in workers:
        w.join()

    while not shared_q.empty():
        print shared_q.get()
```

This gives me the output as follows:

```
Worker-1 init
Worker-2 init
Worker-1 running
Worker-2 running
('Worker-1', 'A')
('Worker-1', 'B')
('Worker-1', 'C')
('Worker-2', 'A')
('Worker-2', 'B')
('Worker-2', 'C')
```

**What I am trying to achieve is this output:**

```
Worker-1 init
Worker-2 init
Worker-1 running
Worker-2 running
('Worker-1', 'A')
('Worker-2', 'A')
('Worker-1', 'B')
('Worker-2', 'B')
('Worker-1', 'C')
('Worker-2', 'C')
```

I have locked at `Lock` and`RLock`, but that doesn't seem to fit the bill, as I am trying to get all the threads running at the same time, but just stop and wait until the others are all finished before executing the next command.

I am sure that there is a nice and simple way to do this, but I can't quite get my head around what it is. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to proceed?

Comment: Firstly, those are processes, not threads.  Secondly, why do you care about the order in which they run?  The whole point of parallel computing is to do things simultaneously.  Limiting them to run in lockstep with each other will reduce your performance.  Since they are separate processes, they cannot see each others' work anyway, so synchronization is usually unnecessary.

Comment: @Kevin I've updated the title. Sorry I didn't explain the context. I'm using this approach for testing a multi-user application. I want to carry out a sequence of operations simultaneously on an API from multiple clients. Without the synchronisation I will have no guarantee that the operations are carried out in the order I expect.

Comment: Why not put the tasks that have to be processed in a defined sequence, as a single list to a single worker? Whether `['A', 'B', 'C']` is processed by a single or multiple workers shouldn't matter when `'B'` needs to wait for `'A'` etc.

Comment: @sebastian I am simulating a multi-user environment, where different users are running an application that points to a shared resource. I want to be able to control what each worker does to produce a repeatable set of tests.

Comment: Using ```map``` to produce a side affect is generally discouraged. Functional programming should not produce side affects.  It is *better* to iterate over the list to put the items in the ```Queue```.

Answer (score 0):

Under Python 3, you would use a [`multiprocessing.Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier) for something like this.  Unfortunately, that doesn't exist in Python 2 (yet another reason to switch!).

For Python 2, you'll probably want to have your individual workers notify the manager that they have finished (say) task A.  The manager waits for a notification from every worker, and then notifies all the workers to move on to the next task.  You can accomplish this by handing *two* events to each worker, instead of the one you're currently using.  One of the events is shared between all the workers, and is used by the manager to notify the workers.  The other event is specific to each worker, and is used to notify the manager.

If you plan on reusing the shared event, there is a race condition between setting and resetting it (i.e. one of the workers might race ahead and wait on the event a second time before you get a chance to reset it).  You may want to use a Condition instead of an Event for the shared case.  The per-worker case does not have this issue as the manager can reset all the per-worker events before setting the shared event.

Answer (score 0):

This class should work to synchronise the processes. It basically holds all the processes on a threading condition, when the last worker is done, it notifies all the other processes which are woken up and are able to continue

worker.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event, Lock

class Worker(Process):

    def __init__(self, execute, q_out, syncher):
        Process.__init__(self)
        print self.name, 'init'
        self.daemon = True
        self.q_in = Queue()
        self.q_out = q_out
        self.execute = execute
        self.syncher = syncher

    def run(self):
        print self.name, 'running'
        self.execute.wait()
        while not self.q_in.empty():
            self.syncher.check()
            cmd = self.q_in.get()
            self.q_out.put((self.name, cmd))
```

manager.py

```
from multiprocessing import Event, Queue, Condition, Lock, Value
from worker import Worker

class Synchroniser(object):
    def __init__(self, workers):
        self.workers_locked = Value('i', 0)
        self.workers = workers
        self.condition = Condition(Lock())

    def check(self):
        with self.condition:
            self.workers_locked.value += 1
            if self.workers_locked.value >= self.workers:
                self.condition.notify_all()
            else:
                self.condition.wait()
            self.workers_locked.value -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':

    workers = []
    syncEvent = Event()
    shared_q = Queue()
    worker_num = 2
    syncher = Synchroniser(worker_num)
    for i in range(0,worker_num):
        worker = Worker(syncEvent, shared_q, syncher)
        map(worker.q_in.put, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
        workers.append(worker)
        worker.start()

    syncEvent.set()

    for w in workers:
        w.join()

    while not shared_q.empty():
        print shared_q.get()
```

---

```
> python manager.py 
Worker-1 init
Worker-2 init
Worker-1 running
Worker-2 running
('Worker-1', 'A')
('Worker-2', 'A')
('Worker-2', 'B')
('Worker-1', 'B')
('Worker-1', 'C')
('Worker-2', 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working a cross-purposes here. On the one hand you dispatch all of the work to the workers at once but on the other hand you want the workers to run in lock-step. You could dispatch the commands one at a time and wait for all results before proceeding. Then you could remove any inter-worker syncing that needs to be done.

```
from multiprocessing import Event, Queue
from worker import Worker

if __name__ == '__main__':    

    shared_q = Queue()
    results = []
    workers = [Worker(syncEvent, shared_q) for _ in range(2)]
    for worker in workers:
        worker.start()
    for worker in workers:
        worker.q_in.put('A')
    for _ in worker:
        results.append(shared_q.get())

    ...

    for w in workers:
        w.join()

    for r in results:
        print results
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already have that case working. As I just said in a comment on the question, I am simulating a multi-user environment, where different users are running an application that points to a shared resource. I want to be able to control what each worker does to produce a repeatable set of tests.

Comment: that's exactly why i wrote this answer. You add to the individual queues in whatever combos you want and then read results to maintain sequence. If you already have this case working, which means that your AABBCC sequence already works... then why the question in the first place?

Comment: This can get more complex, like including sequence numbers so that you know which results are for which commands.

Comment: OK, so another requirement (I possibly haven't mentioned) is that I  want to have the commands executed simultaneously. I.e. All executing 'A' a the same time, e.g. writing a large amount of data to the DB.

Comment: In this example, A goes to all of them at once. They all must complete, and then you could do B, C, etc... the same way.